# Formal definition of a derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If we have a function $f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{x = y} \\
0, & \text{$0$ otherwise}
\end{cases} $

For the following, assume $h \ne 0$.

$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} f_x(x,y) = \frac{f(x + h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}$

We now have the following, which is correct.

$=$ $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0+h, 0) - f(0,0)}{h}$

$= \frac{0 - 1}{h}$

$= -\infty$

For the following, we assume $h = 0$.

$=$ $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0+0, 0) - f(0,0)}{0}$

In the first case, $f(x,y) = 0$, since we are implying that $x \ne y$. But I don't understand why that's the case. In fact, we are taking the limit as $h$ goes to $0$, so shouldn't we have $f(x,y) = 1$, as in the second scenario? The first case does not make sense to me, because we are implying that although $h$ goes to $0$, $f(x+h,y) \ne f(x+0,y)$.

Please explain why this is not the case. Also, please do not give the lazy reasoning 'we cannot divide by zero'. That is not an illuminating explanation. Also, I am not referring to the division by $0$ - I am specifically referring to the mechanics of the $f(x+h,y)$ terms. I am well aware of how limits work but I have never used the formal definition of derivatives, so this example thoroughly confused me. Thank you.

Comment: What would the value of the $\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$ be when $h=0.1$? 0.01? and so on.

Comment: But for a function like $f(x) = x^2$, $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$. Why can't we do that here?

Comment: What would you do with $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$, $\lim_{x \to 0 } f(x)$?  That is essentially what you have in this problem.

Comment: @DisplayName Thanks. I realise this is the case, but I'm looking for a more elaborate explanation that goes into reasoning. I'll leave the question open, in case someone decides to give a slightly more satisfying answer. The purpose of this is so that I can really convince myself that I understand it, which is why I need a slightly more elaborate answer.

Comment: Sounds good.  I'd write more but I have to get to sleep.

Comment: @DisplayName I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Aside: don't forget that variables can be negative numbers. $\lim_{h \to 0} -\frac{1}{h}$ is not $-\infty$; the limit simply does not exist. (however, $\lim_{h \to 0^+} -\frac{1}{h} = -\infty$)

Comment: @Hurkyl You're right. Thank you. Care to have a go at answering the question? With your reputation points, I'm guessing you could give a good explanation. :)

Comment: You have a 3d plot with a 'straight blade' a unit high running diagonally through the origin. Where does calculus come into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistake is assuming $f$ is continuous. We can actually simplify the problem in a way that your error is still manifest:

Define the function

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x = 0 \\ 0 & x \neq 0 \end{cases} $$

Then, we have

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0 $$

It is also true that

$$ g\left( \lim_{x \to 0} x \right) = 1$$

but there is no reason to think $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ and $g(\lim_{x \to 0} x)$ should be related — they are telling you *completely unrelated* information about the function $g$.

$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ tells you what's happening with $g$ *near* $x=0$, but completely ignores the value of $g(0)$ itself. Conversely, $g(\lim_{x \to 0} x)$ is simply $g(0)$.

If $g$ were *continuous*, then the two would be equal (of course, that's just the definition of "continuous"). But in this example, $g$ is not continuous.

This is basically the same function appearing in your problem, since $f(x,0) = g(x)$.

Comment: Excellent answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. You have helped a student today. :)